# Microsoft Exchange with GMail

Tags: java, gmail, exchangewebservices

I am trying to use EWS Java API with Google Mail.

```html
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP1);
ExchangeCredentials credentials = new WebCredentials("me@GMAIL.com","myPass");
service.setCredentials(credentials);
service.setUrl(new URI("<ews_url>"));
```

What is the "ews_url" for google mail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using EWS Java API to call GMail isn't supported.  You can only use it against Exchange 2007 SP1 & higher or Office 365.